# Reloading components in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm creating a math quiz app using `react-native`. I wish to know how to reload all the components, upon clicking the right answer, so that a new question is loaded.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Azfxc for reference

Comment: Edit your questions rather than adding comments as an update please. Also check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking the wrong way. Reloading all the components will just render the same thing. What you are looking for is more a thing like **Redux**.

It will allow you to have a **state container** where all your data live, allowing to store the question number and update it – then components will be rendered to display the new one.

Please take a look at **[redux documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react)**, then at [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) one.

So you would create a dispatch method, e.g. `setQuestion(...)`, which is called when you press a button that will change the question number. The button would be a *presentational component*.
Then, you would have a component that wrap the whole question screen that will be updated because it was bound with `redux` store. It is a *container component*.
See more about presentational and container component [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#presentational-and-container-components).

If you still want to refresh your app, and don't want a predictive state, you could call `app.forceUpdate()` where `app` would be instance of the top component.

Comment: My app generates random numbers, so if I could refresh the page, a random question will be loaded. I understand what you're trying to tell me, but is there a way to just reload the components?